# Query actions performed by administrators on Azure Audit Log

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an app in Azure that can pull audit logs using the Graph API
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/directoryaudit?view=graph-rest-1.0?

I see the Azure Audit Log has records for all kinds of actions, some performed by the users, and other performed by admins.

I want to know if I can know who are the admins by analyzing the response from the `directoryaudit` Graph API.

I do not know who the admins are.
I do not have access to the Azure portal.
My App has 'AuditLog.Read.All' permission, it does not have 'RoleManagement.Read.Directory' permission.
I can not query for admins using the Graph API.
I only have the audit logs.

Is it possible to infer who are the admins by inspecting the audit log records?
I understand I might only get admins with "write" permissions, since "read" operations don't show up on the audit log.
That is a sacrifice I am willing to make.

Comment: Please edit your question to be specific - right now you haven't shown any work of your own, and it's difficult to discern what specific things you want, and what issues you're running into. You've placed several details as comments under the posted answer, and that's really the wrong place for such things.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I updated the question to be very specific. I am not sure what you mean by "any work of my own". I am asking if an analysis can be done. what type of "work of my own" would you expect to see in this type of question?

Comment: Hello @Oded Peer, If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be possible to query the Azure audit log for actions performed specifically by administrators through portal itself.

You just need to add a filter i.e., initiated by(actor) - Name of Admin.

[image]

After adding filter, you can export the result in JSON and CSV format as well.

[image]

**Update 1**

You can see the list of global admin of AAD.

Just go to your AAD->Role and Adminsitrator-> Search for global Adminstaror->

[image]

**Update 2**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits/?&$filter=initiatedBy/user/id eq 'ObjectID'
```

[image]

For workaround you can filter the audit log of all admin like below i have shown for 2 admin.

```
   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits/?&$filter=initiatedBy/user/id eq 'ObjectID of admin1' && id eq 'ObjectID of admin2'
```

[image]

Comment: What I am looking for is having the list of admins, without prior knowledge on who is an admin

Comment: This is correct, but I am looking for a way to figure out who the admins are from the audit log, using the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryaudit-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http Graph API. I have the "AuditLog.Read.All" permission, I do not have "RoleManagement.Read.Directory" permission

Comment: Sorry Oded, I think there is no such kind of build  that tells who is admin from audit log itslef . Even i tried from Micrsoft Graph (Link which you have shared ). Only you can filter out the audit log intiated by actor(where actor can be admin/user/guest). For workaround you can check the admin name from global administror first. Using admin object id you can filter the audit log of that admin.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I do not know the admin ObjectIDs, this is what I am trying to find out.

Comment: As I have mentioned in Update 1 you can see the list of global admin .just click one of the admin name you can see the details of admin from there you can get the ObjectID of admin.

Comment: FYI comments are not the place to hold a conversation. @OdedPeer - I suggest editing your question to be very specific, and also show your work. As it stands, you keep pushing back on the answer provided here, creating additional requirements, and this is not how Stack Overflow works. In any case: if you want to continue a conversation, please move it to [chat], not these comments.